# Promise not rejected when passing error message to Deferred.reject()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I have a JavaScript function that has an asynchronous call to validate a selected option on a form. When I pass a message to the reject() call, it doesn't actually reject the promise. When I remove the message parameter, it works as expected.

```
function myValidationCallback(statusId) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ServersideValidationCall?statusId=" + statusId,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function (res) {
        if(res.IsValid)
            d.resolve()
        else
            d.reject(res.Message); // If res.Message is removed, the reject works.
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.error("Server-side validation error", error);

        d.reject("Cannot contact validation server");
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```

From [jQuery's deferred documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/) and [this](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxValidator/Validation_Rules/AsyncRule/#message) example of validation, it looks like deferred.reject can take a message as an argument.

Edit:
The validation callback function is a validation rule in this DevExtreme selectbox:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/GetStatuses",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#statusId").dxSelectBox().dxValidator({
                validationRules: [{
                    type: "async",
                    validationCallback: function (params) {
                        return myValidationCallback(params.value)
                    }
                }],
                validationGroup: ValidationGroup
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            givePersistentFeedback("detailsExceptionFeedback", "danger", getExceptionError(jqXHR));
        }
    });
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to manually create a deferred object. jQuery's `$.ajax()` creates one for you

Comment: Can you show how you're consuming the `validationCallback` function? How are you verifying that the `d.reject(res.Message)` is not working?

Comment: Updated to show what the promise is being returned to.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with that validation library. Have you tried looking in their issues list? Your code looks the same as their [sample code](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxValidator/Validation_Rules/AsyncRule/#validationCallback). Only other thing to check is that `res.Message` is what you expect it to be

Comment: Remember that `res.message` doesn't necessarily exist. It depends on what your `ServersideValidationCall()` delivers back to the client.